# AngularJS : difference between views and templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am working on angular js application and I have come across a module where `stateProvider` config for this module is done bit different from other modules.

Following is the source code of the module I am confused with.

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('app.authentication', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {


      var home = {
          name: 'app.login',
          url: '/login',
          views: {
            '@': {
              templateUrl: 'components/authentication/login.html'
            }
          }
      };

      $stateProvider.state(home);

  }]);
```

here you can see that `templateUrl` for this module is given inside `views` object and there is `'@'` symbol as well. I am having a hard time understanding the purpose of this block of code. Normally, every other module in the application has the following module structure.

'use strict';

```
angular
  .module('app.home', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

      var home = {
          name: 'app.home',
          url: '/dashboard',
          parent: 'app',
          templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeController',
          controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
      };

      $stateProvider.state(home);

  }]);
```

Could someone help me understand the purpose of `views` and `'@'` syntax and how it differs from `templateUrl`.

Comment: Check here: [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `views` property is used to set up multiple views or to target views manually. So this can be useful if you have multiple named views. According to the [documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.0-beta.1/classes/state.stateprovider.html):

> **views** {object} - returns a views object where each key is an absolute view name (i.e. "viewName@stateName") and each value is the
>   config object (template, controller) for the view. Even when you don't
>   use the views object explicitly on a state config, one is still
>   created for you internally. So by decorating this builder function you
>   have access to decorating template and controller properties.

Inside the `views` property, you could also define a different controller for a particular view, among other options:

```
"views": {
    "app@main": {
        templateUrl: "url/to/template",
        controller: "ControllerName",
        controllerAs: "myController"
    }
}
```

As for the `@` syntax, usually you will see that in combination with a `[uiview path]` and a `[state anchor]`, as described in the UI-Router documentation [section on generalized addressing](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/views#generalized-addressing).

For example, in "app@main", `app` would be the viewName and `main` would be the stateName.

The documentation gives two examples of this:

**Generalized Address Example 1**:

`main.nestedview@home.child`:

This example Targets the `uiview` named `nestedview`, which is nested inside the `uiview` named `main`, which was created by the `home.child` state.

**Generalized Address Example 2**:

`$default.$default@^.^`:

This example Targets the unnamed `uiview`, which is nested inside another unnamed `uiview`, which was created by the grandparent state.

See also:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views
- https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.0-beta.1/classes/state.stateprovider.html